# Is there a way to change title in navigation bar to Italic, Bold and underlined without changing font?

Tags: ios

I use the UIAppearance to change attributes of my title in Navigation Bar like so:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [MM mainTitleColor]}];
```

But I have not found the way to make text underlined or italic, is there a way to do this without changing the font alltogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. These properties you cant change unless font changing. Because the available keys under the **appearance proxy** are

- UITextAttributeFont
- UITextAttributeTextColor
- UITextAttributeTextShadowColor
- UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset

Change these properties to customize the **UINavigationBar**

If you looking for font change, then see the below example

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
    UITextAttributeTextColor: TEXT_COLOR,
    UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: SHADOW_COLOR,
    UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)],
    UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:0.0],
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

You have to customise your navigation controller with adding a `imageview`.

```
UIFont *yourFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-BoldOblique" size:[UIFont systemFontSize]];

if ([[UINavigationBar class]respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) {
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor clearColor],
UITextAttributeTextShadowColor : [UIColor blackColor],
UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset : [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(1, 0)],
UITextAttributeFont : yourFont
}];
```

You can use :

- **Optima-BoldItalic**
- **TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT**
- **Baskerville-BoldItalic**
- **HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic**
- **TrebuchetMS-Bold**
- **Helvetica-BoldOblique**

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to make your text italic and bold.

```
 NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
        shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
        shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                               [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                               shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,
                                                               [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic" size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

        [self setTitle:@"Title text"];
```