# I Want to Bold my Navigation Title At Specific Screen. any Suggestions?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I Have a Scenario in Which only One Screen's Navigation Title Need To Be Bold How It Done? any Suggestion?

I Have Alternate Solution.

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
    [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "MONTSERRAT-BOLD", size: 18)!]
```

In That I Have Font Which Style is BOLD. but i need to know is there any property in iOS Which did BOLD, Italic, Underline My Navigation Title

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change title in navigation bar to Italic, Bold and underlined without changing font?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602826/is-there-a-way-to-change-title-in-navigation-bar-to-italic-bold-and-underlined)

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari ooh Sorry means there is no Property By Apple

Comment: @Indrajeet I tried Code Which i added

Comment: You have to change the appearance of Nav

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Will You Provide Some Piece of Code