# How to set underlined navigation bar title using swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I want to set a underlined navigation bar title using swift 4. Is it possible by using attributed string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to underline a UILabel in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053334/how-to-underline-a-uilabel-in-swift)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602826/is-there-a-way-to-change-title-in-navigation-bar-to-italic-bold-and-underlined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set attributed string to navigation bar title.

```
let navTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "My Title", attributes:
                [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue])
self.title = navTitle.string
```

If navigationController is nil then you can't set title with above code.

Alternatively, you can use custom title view in navigation bar.

```
let titleView = UILabel() // set other table properties
let navTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "My Title", attributes:
                [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue])
titleView.attributedText = navTitle

//set title view to navigation       
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

Comment: Your first block of code won't work since you don't actually use the attributed string.